# The blank page in the appendix in the ieeeconf.cls class

Tags: ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am typing a file in the ieeeconf.cls class. I created my Appendix in a file called ``Appendix". Near the end of the document I am including them as follows (wanting that the Appendix start on the next page than where the last writing ended)

```
\newpage  
\appendix 
\include{Appendix} 
\end{document}
```

But it seems that what it does is to create a blank page with "APPENDIX" written at the top and then it starts typing the file Appendix. Any ideas on how this blank page can be stopped?

Comment: Use `\input` instead of `\include`?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix it!